# Need help setting up a git server on windows

Tags: windows, git

i'm trying to set up a git server on Windows, but i'm having some issues getting it all to work.

I have locally created a normal repository, and remotely i created a bare repository. On the local repository i added a single text file and committed it, but when I try to push it into the remote repository I always get the following message:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: fata
```

I searched SO and other sources, and most of them suggest it's an issue regarding command echos. I'm using freeSSHd as a SSH solution (remote repository is hosted on a windows server), and I tried to use both the git bash and the windows CMD as a command shell.

I start CMD with `/Q` to disable echoing and `/K` to change directory to a directory where repositories are located, so I don't think that would be a problem.

Using the remote desktop, i can clone the repository to a folder next to it, and using the git bash locally i can access the SSH shell and also clone the repository in the same way. But using `git clone ssh://<address>:/myRepo.git` I always get the above message (The SSH's working folder is the same where the repository is located). Does anyone have any idea what's going on? How can I see what command is triggering the error, and how can I see the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also met the same error using `freeSSHd` as a ssh solution for git server on Windows. I couldn't find a solution for a whole day and gave up. :(

Later I found another powerful ssh server from `Bitvise` called [`WinSSHD`](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download) worked well. It has free version for personal use. I suggest you to switch to it. Though I'd also like to know if there's a fix to the error we both met.

To setup ssh server with `WinSSHD` is quite simple, and you can add virtual accounts with private/public key access.

The key part is to setup the ssh access for git server. Please follow the steps of the blog [here](http://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/setting-up-a-git-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2-using-msysgit-and-winsshd-update/).

It should work well for Windows git client. For Mac, you may meet an error as follows.

```
grp.sh: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

To fix it, you need to create the two files `gup.sh` and `grp.sh` in your git bin directory (`GIT_PATH/bin` or `GIT_PATH/libexec/git-core` configured in system environment variable `PATH`) in your git server.

The content of `gup.sh`:

```
git-upload-pack.exe $*
```

The content of `grp.sh`:

```
git-receive-pack.exe $*
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and post results. Thank you.

Comment: I Installed WinSSHD and it worked. I had to give the WinSSHD user full control over the repositories directory, otherwise I would constantly get an error that the repository could not be accessed.